Should the tag 'usage' be removed?
The usage tag has the following description: "General questions about how to use the Bitcoin client or related software and products."
That is a very broad definition and might be applied to any number of questions. It should either be changed to have a narrower, meaningful focus or removed.

I'm all for removing it.

So, this has been proposed about one day ago, and seen by 13 people, but gathered one vote. How does one decide whether there is sufficient support to go ahead with a proposal on meta? Or is it more a "saying sorry, is easier" than "asking permission" style of thing?

Nobody opposed it and this shouldn't be very controversial so it's fine to delete it. And I see now that it already is deleted. :)

alright, splendid ;)

I am a bit confused to see that "usage" is not deleted.

It's been burninated.
